# No Runnable methods error when migrating from Junit4 to Junit5 :

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, junit5

I have just tried to migrate from JUnit 4 to Junit 5 using the official migration guide.

Here is my original class using JUnit 4 :

```
package com.mypack;

import javax.annotation.Autowired;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.annotation.DatabaseSetup;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DatabaseSetup(value = "/db_data/dao/dbunit_file.xml")
public class PersonalTest extends AbstractTU {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDAO someDAO;

    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
        // -- Test details with classic asserts
    }
}
```

And here is the code of the abstract class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/mybeans.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
public abstract class AbstractTU extends AbstractModelTU {
}
```

This used to work correctly, even if it is perfectly clean.
The *AbstractModelTU* class just contains some properly initialized variables used in children classes, it does not add any other annotations.

I have imported junit jupiter and junit vintage in my maven dependencies.
According to the guide, I should change `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4Runner.class)` with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`. I have done that and the class show no compilation error or conflict.

However, I get this error when I run my tests :

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:107)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

On eclipse, I can't even do a *Run as Junit test*, it's not displayed in the menu, despite adding junit 5 support plugin to my Eclipse 4.7 version.

**EDIT :** When I tried to install the plugin again, I had this error : *junit5 support following solutions are not available*

What am I doing wrong ? What am I missing ? Has anyone found a fix to this kind of problem ? It seems like a simple error but I cant figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [current beta support for JUnit 5 in Eclipse 4.7](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/junit-5-support-oxygen), you need to include manually the JUnit 5 library in your project classpath (Build path -> Add libraries -> JUnit -> JUnit 5). Then you should be able of running JUnit 5 tests as usual.

Comment: Currently trying to correct this but I can't find junit5 in the librarires, only junit3 and junit4 are available.

Comment: Do you have "JUnit 5 Support for Oxygen" installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed. I'll get back to you once I've tried your propositions.

Comment: Ok so I can't figure out how to properly install Eclipse 4.7.1 and be able to use your solution. Maybe I'll try again later ... Thanks anyway.

Comment: OK so it appears to be working after following the link you mentioned again. No idea what changed, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Folowing @Boni response I noticed that the link said that eclipse needs to be in 4.7 M-build, but i also found [this link](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-setup/)
that said that eclipse should be in 4.7.1. Furthermore there is a link to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488566#c8) for runing Junit5 in eclipse 4.5 M-build.

if you are not in eclipse 4.7.1 or more you should try to update your eclipse version

Comment: The eclipse update you mentioned is acutally about the eclipse SDK. Following @boni link helped me correct this. Thanks anyway !